# How to add a new line for a missing entry between two fields

Tags: text-processing, scripting, columns

I have this file. As you can see in column1, entries TEST01N03, TEST01N06, 
and TEST01N18 are missing (total of 18 entries).
Is there a way to check the fields of this column and fill in the missing
entries ?

```
TEST01N01 40   2002    2697    2523  
TEST01N02 40   4       4       5    
TEST01N04 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N05 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N07 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N08 40   1       4       5  
TEST01N09 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N10 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N11 40   2002    2621    2617  
TEST01N13 40   1       4       5  
TEST01N14 40   1       4       5    
TEST01N15 40   1       4       5  
TEST01N16 40   1       4       5  
TEST01N17 40   2002    2576    2515
```

The output should look like this:

```
TEST01N01 40   2002    2697    2523  
TEST01N02 40   4       4       5    
TEST01N03 empty  
TEST01N04 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N05 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N06 empty  
TEST01N07 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N08 40   1       4       5  
TEST01N09 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N10 40   4       4       5  
TEST01N11 40   2002    2621    2617  
TEST01N12 empty  
TEST01N13 40   1       4       5  
TEST01N14 40   1       4       5    
TEST01N15 40   1       4       5  
TEST01N16 40   1       4       5  
TEST01N17 40   2002    2576    2515  
TEST01N18 empty
```

Really appreciated for any suggestion of a script to accomplish this.

Comment: Is `N` in `TEST01N01` fixed?

Comment: Yes, TEST01N is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -anle 'BEGIN {$pattern = "TEST01N"}
    $curr = $F[0] =~ s/$pattern//r;
    if ($prev and ++$prev != $curr) {
        printf "%s%02d empty\n", $pattern, $prev;
        redo;
    } 
    $prev = $curr;
    print;
' file
TEST01N01 40 2002 2697 2523
TEST01N02 40 4 4 5
TEST01N03 empty
TEST01N04 40 4 4 5
TEST01N05 40 4 4 5
TEST01N06 empty
TEST01N07 40 4 4 5
TEST01N08 40 1 4 5
TEST01N09 40 4 4 5
TEST01N10 40 4 4 5
TEST01N11 40 2002 2621 2617
TEST01N12 empty
TEST01N13 40 1 4 5
TEST01N14 40 1 4 5
TEST01N15 40 1 4 5
TEST01N16 40 1 4 5
TEST01N17 40 2002 2576 2515
```

**Explanation**

- We get current column index, save in variable `$curr`
- If `$prev` is set and its value plus 1 not equal `$curr`, meaning we have missing entry, print it and redo from the beginning until `$prev` equal `$curr`.
- Assign `$curr` value to `$prev`.
- Print the line.

**Update**

For @Babyy's comment, you can try:

```
$ perl -anle 'BEGIN {$pattern = "TEST01N"}
    $curr = $F[0] =~ s/$pattern//r;     
    if ($. == 1 and (0+$curr) != ++$i) {
        printf "%s%02d empty\n", $pattern, $i;
        redo;
    }
    if ($prev and ++$prev != $curr) {
        printf "%s%02d empty\n", $pattern, $prev;
        redo;
    } 
    $prev = $curr;
    print;
' file
```

Comment: result is mistake on this text http://pastebin.mozilla.org/5545404  , this script not say `TEST01N01`is empty ..

Comment: @Babyy: see my updated!

Comment: Thanks Gnouc ! As much as I would love to use your perl script but I am in the middle of a bash script. And this problem is on my way. I cannot switch to your script yet. If you have any idea how to use bash or ksh script would be great.

Comment: @user66933: You can run it inside your bash script.

Comment: Could you please show me an example ? Sorry ! I'm newbie. Thanks

Comment: @nvt007: Just...run it! Like you run any thing from your bash script. Just type: `perl -anle ...` and the rest. You can copy paste this to your script. Remember to replace `file` with your actual file name.

Comment: @Gnouc : and your code have 2 problem!! first: not say `TEST01N18` in `empty` ( OR tested it on this text http://pastebin.mozilla.org/5545683 ) ;; two: if we have 2 enter on last line, script goto infinity loop! (e.g. `echo -e "\n\n" >> file` then run perl script)

Comment: @ Gnouc: I added the perl script like this into my bash script, where $cfmfile.ready is a variable of a file name that I use in my script, but the output didn't get updated ???. Maybe what I need is to print it to a file ?? '/usr/bin/perl -anle 'BEGIN {$pattern = "TEST01N"}
    $curr = $F[0] =~ s/$pattern//r;
    if ($. == 1 and (0+$curr) != ++$i) {
        printf "%s%02d empty\n", $pattern, $i;
        redo;
    }
    if ($prev and ++$prev != $curr) {
        printf "%s%02d empty\n", $pattern, $prev;
        redo;
    }
    $prev = $curr;
    print;
' $cfmfile.ready'

Comment: @Babyy: Yes, it's not designed for handling that. Maybe just `next if /^$/;` to fix it. If you have any problem, you can try to fix it yourself.

Comment: @nvt007: Yes, you should print it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

In awk: parse each input line to find the `current` index after the `TEST01N` prefix. If the current output line number (`n`) is less than the index, print missing lines before copying the input line. Finally add more lines to reach the desired count.

```
{
    i = match($1,/[0-9]+$/);
    prefix = substr($1,1,i-1);
    current = substr($1,i) + 0;
    while (++n < current) printf "%s%02d empty\n", prefix, n;
    print;
 }
 END {
    while (++n <= 18) printf "%s%02d empty\n", prefix, n;
 }
```

Comment: @ Gilles: Thanks for the script. I will test it soon. I like using awk.